# Can I cast nullptr to other pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I do this?

```
static_cast<A*>(getSomePtr());
```

where `getSomePtr()` will return `nullptr`. Is this ok?

Comment: That's  what `nullptr` is for.

Comment: What is the return type of `getSomePtr()`? Is it actually `std::nullptr_t` or is it the null pointer value of some actual pointer type? Returning `std::nullptr_t` from a function is very weird, and if it's not `std::nullptr_t` then you don't need to cast it because it isn't `nullptr` anyway.

Comment: What matters is the *type*. The value of a pointer doesn't influence whether a cast is valid or not.

Comment: This depends entirely on what you mean by "other pointer type". And also, do you mean null pointer or `nullptr`? They're different things. It would've been useful to write the return type explicitly into the question.

Comment: You don't need a function to return `nullptr`: the type of the value of `nullptr` only admits one value, which is that one value, so you may as well replace the function with the constant of that value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant):

> ...null pointer constant: `nullptr`. It is of type
>   `nullptr_t`, which is implicitly convertible and comparable to any
>   pointer type or pointer-to-member type. It is not implicitly
>   convertible or comparable to integral types, except for `bool`.

`nullptr` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type so explicit conversion with `static_cast` is absolutely valid.

Comment: Do you define "redundant" as OK?

Comment: @zenith I'm answering the question. The function `getSomePtr()` can return `nullptr`, but sometimes the cast can be useful. The use of the cast is OK in this context. (Answer fixed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you deduct the return type of a function and in one branches you have `return nullptr` and something else in other branches, the deduction will fail unless you explicitly cast `nullptr`.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect that you are confused about the difference between *a null pointer* and `nullptr`, they are not the same.

This function returns `nullptr`:

```
std::nullptr_t getNullPtr() { return nullptr; }
```

But that is a pretty useless thing to return, there is very rarely a good reason to return an object of that type.

This function returns a null pointer:

```
A* getAPtr() { return nullptr; }
```

The return value is initialized with `nullptr` but it is actually a null pointer of type `A*`, not `nullptr` itself.

For the first function, yes, you can cast the returned `std::nullptr_t` to another pointer type (you don't even need a cast to do the conversion, it will happen implicitly) but that's probably not something you ever want to do.

For the second function you don't need to cast it because it already returns the right type.

Comment: Presumably the reason he needs to cast it in the question is because `getSomePtr()` doesn't return an `A*`.

Comment: And as I said in my answer, returning `nullptr_t` from a function is not very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to the answers given so far, but generalising your question a little (about the casting of return values, see the other answers): Casting `nullptr` explicitly is not only valid, there are a few situations where it even is unavoidable! For instance, if there are several overloaded functions, each of them accepting a different pointer type and you need to (for whatever reason) call one of them with `nullptr`...

```
void f(int*) { /*...*/ }
void f(double*) { /*...*/ }
void g()
{
    f(nullptr); // compilation error, ambiguous call!
    f(static_cast<int*>(nullptr)); // now compiler knows...
}
```

Well, actually you could cast `f` as well:

```
static_cast<void(int*)>(f)(nullptr);
```

which would select the correct overload, too. Which one is nicer? Choose you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. It will still be null, so it's not safe to call access its members or data, but you can ask questions about its structure at compile-time.

For example, this is a [possible implementation of the `offsetof(type, member)` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) in `<cstddef>`, in which nullptr is cast to a valid type:

```
#define offsetof(type,member) ((std::size_t) &((static_cast<type*>(nullptr))->member))
```

Comment: What has `offsetof` got to do with the question? I don't think adding that clarifies anything.

Comment: The original question was "Can I cast nullptr to another pointer type". The `offsetof` example shows that this can be done, and why one might do so in practice.

Comment: That's constructing an rvalue object of type `type*` which is a whole other thing. Casting `nullptr` when constructing rvalue pointers of a specific type is the only legitimate reason for casting `nullptr` (not a null pointer).

Comment: It's unclear to me what point you are trying to make. For example, is your contention about the casting of `nullptr` instead of `0`, or the use of `static_cast` vs `reinterpret_cast` vs c-style cast? Perhaps you could rephrase your answer. It would be helpful if you were able to provide an example that demonstrates why this particular use case is not legitimate.